# How to increment score when a condition is met using list comprehensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

"""Write a program to count the number of occurrences of substring in  mystring"""

```
mystring = "abcdcdcdc"
substring = "cdc"
score = 0
ss_len = len(substring)
for i in range(len(mystring)):
    if mystring[i : i + ss_len] == substring:
        score += 1
print(score)
```

Hello,

How do I write the above working code using a list comprehension? This returns 3 as the result

Below is what I have and that doesn't work as expected.

```
s = [score = score +1 for i in range(len(substring)) if mystring[i : i + ss_len] == substring ]
print(s)
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use mystring.count(substring)  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `sum()` to get the amount to add to `score`

```py
score = sum([1 for i in range(len(mystring)) if substring==mystring[i:i+len(substring)]])
```

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Now it looks nice

Answer (score 1):

A correction in above code you can just use
@Shazers answer is correct but you can just edit a little bit for better performance

```
s = sum([1 for i in range(len(mystring)) if substring==mystring[i:i+len(substring)]])
```